# Multidimensional array, if array value exists, create new array following that value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have decided to set up an array to differentiate certain values. If I look to find a certain value in the array, I'd like to use the rest of the data within this value I have searched:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Burger Joint
                    [pluralName] => Burger Joints
                    [shortName] => Burgers
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 617
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => reeeJoint
                    [pluralName] => reeeJoints
                    [shortName] => reee
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12355
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => LeftJoint
                    [pluralName] => LeftJoints
                    [shortName] => Left
                )

        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 526
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => asdfJoint
                    [pluralName] => asdfJoints
                    [shortName] => asdf
                )

        )
)
```

I'd like to do some kind of search where if there's a value with `123`, it will only get a new array with everything in the 123 id array (in this case is the first one).

What is the best practice in finding this?

Thanks!

Edit:

Based on some comments, I was able to come up with a new way of setting my array. However I'm still wondering the same question which way to tackle showing if value exists:

```
foreach($values as $value)
{
 ...
   $categoriesExtract[$id] = array($category_stringArray2Sugg);
}
```

gives me this array:

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Burger Joint
                    [pluralName] => Burger Joints
                    [shortName] => Burgers
                )

        )

    [617] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => reeeJoint
                    [pluralName] => reeeJoints
                    [shortName] => reee
                )

        )

    [12355] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => LeftJoint
                    [pluralName] => LeftJoints
                    [shortName] => Left
                )

        )
    [526] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => asdfJoint
                    [pluralName] => asdfJoints
                    [shortName] => asdf
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: You should be using objects - not arrays. If you turned this into a single array of objects, which had an array for a member variable, it would be alot easier to understand.

Comment: what output do you want. can you show here?

Comment: @NicholasPickering I updated my answer to show how I got my array. Can explain how I would be able to do it in objects?

Comment: @Roopendra I'd like to just show an array of `name,pluralName,shortName` Just getting those data so I can echo out in json format

Comment: @andrewliu , Check my answer hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the id as the key, then pull out the key?

```
$array = Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [name] => Burger Joint
            [pluralName] => Burger Joints
            [shortName] => Burgers
        )

    [617] => Array
        (
            [name] => reeeJoint
            [pluralName] => reeeJoints
            [shortName] => reee
        )
)


$new_array = $array[123];
```

You had 2 items with the ID 123, which would mean this situation wouldn't work, but in your question you indicated you wanted the first value returned. Is the double up on the ID an error, or is it something that can legitimately happen because this will mean this won't be a suitable way of doing it.

Comment: Sorry, that 123 was a typo. each array is supposed to have a unique id. I've updated my array to show something similar

Comment: This actually lead me to the answer i was looking for. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. It will create new array following the match.

```
 $arr = array();
 for($i = 0;$i<count($array);$i++)
 {
     if($array[$i][id] == 123)
     {
          $arr[] = $array[$i][0];
     }
 }
 print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do like this:

```
$array = array(0 => 
                  array('id' => 123,
                        0 => array('name' => 'Burger Joint',
                                   'pluralName' => 'Burger Joints',
                                   'shortName' => 'Burgers')
                                   )
                );

$new_array =  array();
foreach($array as $value){
   $new_array[$value['id']][] = $value[0];
}
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Burger Joint
                    [pluralName] => Burger Joints
                    [shortName] => Burgers
                )

        )

)
```

Cheeers !!!!!

Check working demo here [working demo link](http://codepad.org/gO7tQz3n)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution : Here change the values in `$find` array to search for ids

```
$array  = Array(Array("id" => 123,0 => Array("name" => "Burger Joint","pluralName" => "Burger Joints","shortName" => "Burgers")),
                Array("id" => 617,0 => Array("name" => "reeeJoint","pluralName" => "reeeJoints","shortName" => "reee")),
                Array("id" => 12355,0 => Array("name" => "LeftJoint","pluralName" => "LeftJoints","shortName" => "Left")),
                Array("id" => 526,0 => Array("name" => "asdfJoint","pluralName" => "asdfJoints","shortName" => "asdf"))
                );
$find   = array(123,526); /// Get all the array with this id

$result = array();
foreach($array as $vals){
    if(in_array($vals['id'],$find)){
        $result[]  = $vals;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I just made something easy more complicated...

Because of the suggestions, I was just able to get the array by doing this

$array(123); => this will just get me the array that has the value 123...